# It Happened That, As It Happened

Tags: discourse-context

Is there a difference here:

> 1. ***It happened that*** he did not go to work today.
> 2. ***As it happened***, he did not go to work today.

Do "it happened that" and "as it happened" have different meanings?

Comment: context is required for a good answer. These are complete sentences but depending on the context, their meanings may change.

Comment: @meatie To me the difference is not about what happened, but how the speaker tells the listener what happened. If the speaker said, "It happened that ...", it would sound like "It probably shouldn't have happened, but it happened anyway, that ..." (so it would sound like what happened probably happened by chance). If speaker chose to say, "As it happened, ...", it would sound like the speaker stated what happened more neutrally, but firmly, i.e. "This was what happened: (Or according to what happened,) he did not ...".

Comment: They mean the same if stand independently. But they may mean different if said in a particular context. *That unfortunate night, he was just about to leave for the party. But then suddenly, some robbers rushed into his house and vandalized things. As it happened, he did not attend the party.*

Comment: @DamkerngT. That old question was so poorly worded that I had to write a new one.  Some contributors on that old question thread were mislead by the semantics of the portion of the sentence after "it happened that" and "as it happened".

Comment: As @MaulikV mentioned, 2 is usually used as part of a dialogue of events, while 1 is just a statement of fact; what is before and after it can be unrelated.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they (can) have different meanings, depending on context.

**As it happened**, or **as it happens**, normally describes a single occurrence of a situation.

> We always went to the candy store after school, but as it happened, that fateful day, the store was closed.

**It happened** or **it happens** can be used to describe something that occurs more than once. It is maybe not the most common thing, but it does occur from time to time.

> We always went to the candy store after school, but it happened that the store would be closed. Then we would sit at the coffee shop next door.

Comment: I edited my original question.  Are "it happened that.." and "as it happened, ..." different?

Comment: @meatie: I think I used exactly those two phrases in my examples, and my answer is valid for both the present and the simple past tense.

Answer (score 1):

Maulik and user3169 have sketched the difference.

- *It happened that* introduces a new event to a narrative, usually one that turns the narrative in a new direction and launches a new phase of the action.
- *As it happened* reports an event whose occurrence was previously in doubt or not expected, often in contrast to what was expected.

*As it happened* may also be an ordinary temporal clause, introducing an account of what was happening at the same time as 'it'.

Comment: Sometimes "*so*" and "*just so*" are used with both "*it happened*" and "*as it happened*".  What extra meanings do "so" and "just so" add?

Comment: *It so happened* or *it so fell out* are just more leisurely ways of saying the same thing. I can't imagine when *As it so happened* would be possible.

Comment: A google search of the phrase "as it just so happened" returned about 27 million hits.  So, those hits must be instances of poor writing?

Comment: @meatie (**Never** believe that 'estimate' Google gives you. Track through the pages and Google actually reports only 399.) This seems to be a new colloquial marriage of the two expressions; Google Books has only 5 instances, one in 1975 and the rest in the 21st century.

Comment: The meanings of the two expressions are so close.  Could the distinction be disappearing among native speakers?

Comment: @meatie Possibly. They're both mostly literary, and epressions like that get very fluid when they trickle into the spoken language.